# Get Parent div on button click

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html:

```
<div id = "CompOne">
    <div id="btns">
        <input type="button" value="Add" class="cartbtn" onclick="SetSubmitBundleValue(this)">
    </div>
</div>

<div id = "CompTwo">
    <div id="btns">
        <input type="button" value="Add" class="cartbtn" onclick="SetSubmitBundleValue(this)">
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want to get value of the parent div `CompTwo`/ `CompOne` on their button click. Is it possible to retrieve this value from the object passed through the 'this' keyword? Kindly help

```
function SetSubmitBundleValue(obj)
{
    //Get Parent div
}
```

Comment: i think in jQuery you can get parent with `.parent()` so `$(this).parent()` but this would get the parent div of the input.

Comment: Empty function? You did not even try to solve this on your own, did you?

Comment: @Toxide82 - $(this).parent().parent()

Comment: @mpf82 - he did not even search his own title

Comment: yeah I know i missed one thought that the person would get that though and at least try to solve it from there lol.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `parent()` method:

```js
$('.cartbtn').on('click', function(){
 var parent_id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
 console.log(parent_id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "CompOne">
    <div id="btns">
        <input type="button" value="Add" class="cartbtn">
    </div>
</div>

<div id = "CompTwo">
    <div id="btns">
        <input type="button" value="Add" class="cartbtn">
    </div>
</div>
```